# Return types for recursive async generator function

Tags: typescript, recursion, types, generator

What are the correct types to define the following recursive async function generator?

```
async function* recursive_f(n: number): AsyncGenerator<number, ?, ?> {
    n++
    if(n>0) {
        yield n
        return await recursive_f(n)
    }

    return Promise.resolve()
}
```

The following code is not working as expected. It should recursively decrease n and yield it once negative, instead it will pass the if condition and end.

```
async function* recursive_f(n: number): AsyncGenerator<number> {
    
    if (n < 0) {
        yield n
    }

    return await recursive_f(n--) // 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.
}

async function main_function() {
    console.log(`main_function`)
    let num = 10
    for await (const n of recursive_f(num)) {
        console.log(n)
    }
}

main_function().then(console.log, console.error)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to achieve; you want `recursive_f(10)` to generate what set of numbers exactly?  Is it just `-1`?  Or is it all numbers from `10` down to `1` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9Brm)?  Why are you trying to call the function recursively instead of iterating?  Is it just to play with recursion or is there some actual use case?  I'm more confused now than when this question was first asked 

Comment: I need `recursive_f` to yield `-1` but decreasing `n` recursively, I'm just playing here but I'm not able to create a chain to do that

Comment: Okay then, so is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGnG0m) what you want?  If that works I'll edit my answer.  If that is not what you want, can you elaborate possibly?  Note that deferring to another generator is most simple with the `yield*` operator instead of trying to re-`yield` the results manually.  This is possible if you must, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgrG1W), but I'm not sure why you'd do that.  Also note that you're not really doing anything asynchronous there, such as even a simple "sleep" like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYJ2xw).  Which, if any of those, should I include?

Answer (score 0):

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes a use case, I can't tell if the following works for your needs, so please check it.

---

You can define a [recursive type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases) like this:

```
type RecursiveF = AsyncGenerator<number, void | RecursiveF>;
```

That means: a `RecursiveF` is an asynchronous generator function that yields a `number`, and returns either a `void` or a `RecursiveF`.  In practice that seems hard to use, since a value of type `void` can't really be inspected.  But that's up to you, and your use case.

Anyway, now you can annotate the return type of `recursiveF` with it:

```
async function* recursive_f(n: number): RecursiveF {
  n++
  if (n > 0) {
    yield n
    return recursive_f(n)
  }

  return Promise.resolve()
}
```

That works in the sense that the compiler agrees with it.  Whether or not it meets your needs is for you to see.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIDEoF4oBBVEAO3gHEIyJkBDYAe2QB4zEBbAIzoBoomJugAmUAD6wEKDNhwA+ANwAoZfVIUoAM0QVg6JmQBUUZNLRYIAfS0AKMgC4oHHnQCUTuEgtyoAb2UoZwBqYMCodC0oeyh5KAAGN39woJB0CAAbMTIU0whgFDI871lrOzI3cIBfVSCzAuQigAVkJk50VAgAOjNUJgzsW0qaoA)

Comment: so the problem is that the compiler is not able to infer the returning type when it encounter a recursive async function? isn't this a missing functionality?

Comment: with your solution the compiler stops complaining about the returning types but when I add `await` to the first `return` I get `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression`

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] (especially in the form of a TS Playground link) which demonstrates the issue, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Oh I see you edited the question; I will look when I get a chance

Comment: I've added a mre

Comment: Oh, if your code doesn’t work *at runtime*, then that’s a different question.  I thought you just wanted the types to be correct, not that your algorithm was broken and didn’t work.  When I get a chance to look (currently on mobile and can’t code) I may or may not be able to do anything about your runtime woes...